# No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}

Tags: python, gradient, loss-function

i was trying to build a PINN model, but when i want to apply gradient to the optimizer it shows the following error, I'm skeptical that the loss function is not differentiable with respect to the biases

i was applying gradients i got from the loss function which is the residual of my diferential equation
Original file is located at
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16QQuspZpmR7QwIDQ2m7ATr5Yl8qrdneL

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 1))
u = tf.zeros(1000)

def residus(x):
  with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(x)
    with tf.GradientTape() as gg:
      gg.watch(x)
      [u,_] = u_model(x)
    ux = gg.gradient(u, x)
  uxx = g.gradient(ux, x)
  residus = uxx
  return residus

def u_model(x):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input(1),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="tanh"),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="tanh"),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])
  u = model(x)
  return [u, model.trainable_variables]

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
[_, tv] = u_model(x)

epochs = 1000 
for _ in range(epochs):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tp:
        cost_fn = residus(x)
    gradients = tp.gradient(cost_fn, tv)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, tv))
```

Comment: You forgot to include the error.